# Limit character sequnce repetition in a word

Tags: regex

I'm working on an Angular web application. An expression is used to check the first and last name.

Allowed characters - letters and "_","-". How to limit the repetition of the characters - and _ in the word?
I need to exclude repetitions like "A-a-a-a". Allowed:
- maximum 1 "-" character and 1 underscore,
- 2 "-" characters or 2 "_" characters, while they must be separated by at least 3 letters.

I have some basic expression that works fine, but does not take this into account:

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)(?![_-])(?!.*[_-]{2})[a-zA-Z_-]+(?<![_-])$
 └─────┬────┘└───┬──┘└─────┬─────┘└─────┬──┘ └───┬───┘
       │         │         │            │        no _ or - at the end
       │         │         │         allowed characters
       │         │       no __ or _- or -_ or -- inside
       │       no _ or - at the beginning
    name is 3-15 characters long
```

Examples to pass:

```
abcdef-xyz
abc-defxyz
abc-def
abc_def
abc-def-ghi
abc-def_ghi
abc_def_ghi
```

Examples that should not pass:

```
_qwerty
qwerty_
-qwerty
qwerty-
asd--fff
zxc__cvb
sdf-_cvb
a-b
ab-c
ab-cd
abc-de
a-b-c-d
a_b_c_d
a-b-c_d
```

etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide many examples. Give a list of examples which should pass and a list of examples which should not pass. As text, directly here.

Comment: Please define the regex flavor you are using, i.e. name the regex engine, the tool you are using.

Comment: ^ Also. Could you define what is considered repetition. Would *"abc-def_def"* be repetition too?

Comment: why _qwerty and qwerty_ are not passing? You did not specified it

Comment: And also this examples should pass according to your spec: a-b,
ab-c,
ab-cd,
abc-de

Comment: Are combinations of - and _ allowed? You did not specified it in the spec. Please give time to write down what you exactly want.

Comment: Almost there! If the string contains one `"_"` and one `"-"` must they be separated by at least 3 other characters? Can the string be empty? If not, can the string contain fewer than 2 characters other than `"_"` and `"-"`?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this bulky regex. I honestly think that regex could be not the best idea for this task. But it was a fun task to do

```
^((?=[^-_]*-[^-_]{3,}-[^-_]*$)|(?=[^-_]*-[^-_]{3,}_[^-_]*$)|(?=[^-_]*_[^-_]{3,}-[^-_]*$)|(?=[^-_]*[-_][^-_]*$)|[^-_\n]+$)[\w-]*$
```

breakdown
we are matching every `[\w-]*` (any number of word characters including underscore and dash)
with restrictions
it should be one of:

`(?=[^-_]*-[^-_]{3,}-[^-_]*$)` two dashes with at least 3 characters between

`(?=[^-_]*-[^-_]{3,}_[^-_]*$)` dash and underscore with at least 3 characters between

`(?=[^-_]*_[^-_]{3,}-[^-_]*$)` undercore and dash with at least 3 characters between

`(?=[^-_]*[-_][^-_]*$)` just one dash or underscore

`[^-_\n]+$` no dash or underscore

demo
https://regex101.com/r/3MdB5Q/4

As you understand it is hardly extensible on more restrictions like "max 3 dashes" with this approach. The reason is regex is not really the tool when you need to count. You could do it with tricks, but as you see it is hard to extend and also to read for other developers. So better use some counting features of the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex if:

- `'_'` and `'-'`, when they are both present in the string, must be separated by at least three characters other than `'_'` and `'-'` (as required when two `'_'`'s or two `'-'`'s are present in the string); and
- the string contains at least two characters than `'_'` and `'-'`.

Neither of these requirements are essential but they greatly simplify the regex.

```
^(?=.{3,15}$)[^_-]{1,}(?:[_-]?(?:[^_-]{3,}[_-])?)?[^_-]{1,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT5B5v/2/)

The regex can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
/
^              # match beginning of line
(?=.{3,15}$)   # match 3-15 chars followed by end-of-line
[^_-]{1,}      # match 1+ chars other than '_' and '-'
(?:            # begin a non-capture group
  [_-]?        # optionally match '_' or '-'
  (?:          # begin a non-capture group
    [^_-]{3,}  # match 3+ chars other than '_' and '-'
    [_-]       # match '_' or '-'
  )?           # end non-capture group
)?             # end non-capture group
[^_-]{1,}      # match 1+ chars other than '_' and '-'    
$              # match end of line
/x             # free-spacing regex definition mode
```